# OS X: LaunchDaemon not running: Service could not initialize

Tags: macos, launchd, launchctl

I used [Apple's seemingly straightforward docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001762-104142) to create a LaunchDaemon to run a Node.js script I wrote.

Here's the `plist` file. It's basically exactly a copy-paste from Apple's docs, set to run every 300 seconds:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.wintr.eodemail</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>~/projects/eod_email/eod</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>300</integer>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/eod-email.log</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/eod-email.log</string>
    <key>Debug</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Here's the error I get in `/var/log/system.log`:

```
Jul 22 10:55:52 Nick-Cox com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.wintr.eodemail[7097]): Service could not initialize: 14E46: xpcproxy + 13421 [1402][7D917364-B96E-3F93-B923-A89B5BF5736D]: 0x2
```

What I've done:

- It has the same permissions as the rest of the files in /Library/LaunchDaemons (`-rw-r--r--`, owned by root)
- I read the [docs for xpc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/xpc.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/xpc), but that didn't help much.
- I made sure that the Node.js script was adequately permissive (777), and runnable from the command line (it is).
- Tried the absolute path to the file (`/Users/nickcox/projects/eod_email/eod`) and made sure I ran `launchctl unload (daemonname)` and `launchctl load (daemon name)`

This seems much more complicated than cron, which is apparently deprecated, according to those Apple docs. What do I need to do to get this script to run on a schedule?

Comment: tilde expansion is not going to work in 10.10 and above( at least that I know of). Use the absolute path. Your script perms should be 755. And I think that JavaScriptCore is not daemon safe.

Comment: See comment about absolute path in "What I've done." And it shouldn't matter if the script perms are _overly_ permissive, right? It would only not work if it was not permissive enough, right? But to your last point, if that's the case, am I out of luck?

Comment: I recommend that you read technical note- TN2083. Documentation does lags behind the ever changing launchd.

Comment: For anyone that finds this, @fd0 is referring to [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html)

Answer (score 6):

Getting started with launchctl can definitely be a frustrating experience. I found a lot of articles explaining what you should do but few little downloadable samples. Here is a simple LaunchDaemon that will hopefully be a good starting point. You can just [download the files here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=53009181764173141047&t=5300918176417314104736251) if you don't feel like copying and pasting.

**Note: you need to replace MY_USER_NAME with your username.** The plist needs to find your script.

```
// at ~/Desktop/testdaemon/com.wintr.eodemail.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.wintr.eodemail</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/MY_USER_NAME/Desktop/testdaemon/testdaemon.sh</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/eod-email.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/eod-email.log</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>15</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This is a simple daemon script that will append the datetime to a file on your desktop. **Note: since the script is run as root, tilde (~) won't be the home directory you expect.**

```
// at ~/Desktop/testdaemon/testdaemon.sh
#!/bin/sh
home="/Users/MYUSERNAME" ## note -- this will be run as root, ~ is not your normal user
now=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S")
echo $now >> "$home/Desktop/TestFile.txt"
```

Finally, I always write a little shell script to install the LaunchDaemons since it's easy to make a mistake. **Since launchctl runs your script as root it requires that script's permissions not be writeable by others, since that would essentially give them root privileges.**

```
// ~/Desktop/testdaemon/install.sh
#!/bin/sh -e
plist_path="com.wintr.eodemail.plist"
plist_filename=$(basename "$plist_path")
install_path="/Library/LaunchDaemons/$plist_filename"

echo "installing launchctl plist: $plist_path --> $install_path"
sudo cp -f "$plist_path" "$install_path"
sudo chown root "$install_path"
sudo chmod 644 "$install_path"

sudo launchctl unload "$install_path"
sudo launchctl load "$install_path"

echo "to check if it's running, run this command: sudo launchctl list | grep wintr"
echo "to uninstall, run this command: sudo launchctl unload \"$install_path\""
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had a different problem, but through this example, and filtering logs in console on "launchd", I was able to identify my problem as one of permissions: I make sure that the plist and script were owned by root and not writable by others, and make sure I ran launchctl via sudo.

Answer (score -2):

It would help if you could paste output of `launchctl list | grep 'com.wintr.eodemail'`.

Also, checkout your `/var/log/eod-email.log` file. It may give you exact errors.

I recommend to install the `brew cask install launchcontrol`, which is a gui tool for launchctl, it can help detect errors and trouble shooting.

Comment: A privative program into homebrew? Spam.